# RESTful API communication between multiple web servers

Tags: angularjs, rest, api

I'm trying to understand RESTful communication, but I still have a few doubts.

Architecture here: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVEPR.png)

I have a main web application (on the right side of the Architecture) made in AngularJS, which shows data coming from multiple web servers containing other applications or databases (on the left side). Some of these applications don't have a REST api and some do, so I imagined putting a REST api interface between those applications and the AngularJS web app would facilitate the work.

My problem is, i don't properly know those REST api from the applications on the left side.

My current "solution" for this, is to register each application, including its endpoints, resources, etc. Assuming some of those endpoints use SSE (Server Sent Events) and some others just display specific data, I though of something like this:

UML diagram here: [uml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67sK8.png)

I separate the endpoints from the ones offering SSE so that I can apply long lopping in angularjs, as well as per methods, in order to use only the ones related to GET to obtain data, and PUT to update, and so on.

My questions is, does this make sense at all? Is this the right way to do it?

I'm aware, that if some of those applications already have a REST api , I could access it directly using $http or ngResource in AngularJS. But what if I don't entirely know this REST api, or what if it hasn't even been done yet ?

Thank you!

Comment: what is the server side technology used?

Comment: Java with Jersey (JAX-RS)  in NginX for the AngularJS app. Apache Tomcat for the other web severs.